# Unable to open web browser link after starting flask server

Tags: python, flask

My `twilio_receive_msg.py` file bears the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_monkey():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.message("Hello, Mobile Monkey")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run `python twilio_receive_msg.py`, the code keeps running like forever and I see the following.

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 135-602-230
```

Also, I am not able to open 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'. I paste the link in my browser, a message appears that says `waiting for 127.0.0.1....` and this message persists even after a long wait!

My OS is Windows and browser is chrome. I tried Explorer too but got the same message.

Can anybody assist me with this? Why am I not able to open the above link?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say you are not able to open the link? What does your browser say? Your server has started correctly, the code is correct too (I've just check it myself).

Comment: I meant when I paste the link in my browser, a message appears that says 'waiting for 127.0.0.1....' and this message persists even after a long wait.

Comment: What OS are you using, what browser? It could be there is a firewall in place that prevents services from running on localhost, or there is already another service active on port 5000 that isn't responding anymore.

Comment: I am using windows and using chrome as a browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried opening the link on explorer too but still cannot access the link. I am getting the same message `waiting for 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Batool what if you try to change either an IP address, or port. Just change your app.run to something like this: `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)`, then open up link `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`. You can try with 127.0.0.1, but another port

Comment: @vrs: `0.0.0.0` means: bind to all interfaces. You can't use that same IP address in the browser; you'd still use 127.0.0.1 or any of the IP addresses set on network cards.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I had tried setting `host = "0.0.0.0"` in the past. That did not work. I've just added `port=5000, debug=True` but I am getting this error for both port and debug : `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'debug'`. Do you know why this might be so?

Comment: @Batool: the arguments apply to the `app.run()` function, not to the `Flask()` instance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for that correction! I ran `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)` and got a message related to firewall blocking the access. I clicked on 'allow access' and got this message on my browser `This site can’t be reached`. Then I tried using my machine's ip address instead of "0.0.0.0" and got the same previous message `waiting for 192.16....`

Answer (score 1):

After long searches i tried localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 in the internet explorer and it worked.